# custom validation error messages with html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, message

Is there a way to add html to custom validation error messages within the validates function?

For example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :legacy_code, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/,
    :message => "Only letters allowed <a href=\"www.example.com\"> Check here </a> " }
end
```

Doing the above simply gives a string literal without the browser interpreting it as html with the  tag.

I tried using locale but it seems like a more complicated way to do it. I've googled a bunch of websites and also tried to override the field_error_proc method.

For example:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  errors = Array(instance.error_message).join(',')
  %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;#{errors}</span>).html_safe

end
```

The above works but gives twice the number of error messages than intended.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

**Solved** by using .html_safe in error message partial:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg.html_safe %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just make sure that the user doesn't have the ability to put anything into your error messages without it being sanitized.

Answer (score 4):

When you output your error, use `raw`

```
<%= raw f.errors %>
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks. where do I put this command? I am using rails 3.2.3 and I have this line in the form view: <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

Comment: In your error messages partial, I suppose? `app/views/shared/_error_messages.*`

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks! what I did was to use the .html_safe command on the error message as in the above edited question. You got it right, I do have to edit the partial error_messages file :) 2 thumbs up!